# Matlab - OCR Languages Support Package Installation

Tags: matlab, installation, ocr, tesseract

Today I wanted to install OCR Languages Support Package on Matlab (using visionSupportPackages function) and I encountered a following a problem:

[image]

by which I can't coplete installation. On this site: tesseract-ocr.googlecode.com I learned that this project was moved. What should I download now to complete installation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The old `traineddata` files can be found at https://sourceforge.net/projects/tesseract-ocr-alt/files/.